# Make SimpleDateFormat.parse() fail on invalid dates (e.g. month is greater than 12)

Tags: java, parsing, date

I'm using `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` to parse strings of the form `"yyyyMMdd"`.

If I try to parse a string with a month greater than 12, instead of failing, it rolls over to the next year. Full runnable repro:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class ParseDateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        Date result = format.parse("20091504"); // <- should not be a valid date!
        System.out.println(result); // prints Thu Mar 04 00:00:00 CST 2010
    }
 }
```

I would rather have a `ParseException` thrown.

Is there any non-hacky way of forcing the exception to happen?. I mean, I don't want to manually check if the month is greater than 12. That's kind of ridiculous.

Thanks for any suggestion.

NOTE: I already know about Joda Time, but I need this done in plain JDK without external libraries.

Comment: For any new readers to this old question I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 146, accepted):

You need to make it [non-lenient](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29). Thus,

```
format.setLenient(false);
```

should do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That did the trick. Amazing how asking questions here gives result faster than searching on google (or I suck at searching :).

Comment: stackoverflow should allow users to give more than 1 point to answers and this is one of those answers. I was doing some ridiculous pattern matching before parsing with `SimpleDateFormat`. Thanks alot.

Comment: setLenient(false) still doesn't work when we give format like "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" and we pass date like "10/25/16 17:46". It didn't check that year is not specified as 2016.

Comment: @AjaySharma: that's not an invalid date.

Comment: also for date format make sure you have month in captials. eg `dd/mm/yyyy` won't work as `mm` stands for minutes not month. valid format should be 'dd/MM/yyyy' in this case.  [see here in documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat)

Comment: @BalusC, If I use the format 'dd-MM-yy' and parse the date value '20-02-199', it is not throwing any parse error instead it is providing the result '20-02-99' but I'm expecting to be throw parse exception since the given date format is not matching with the format I set to SimpleDateFormat. Any Idea?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Java 8 time API. If by example you use a month with a value of `15`:

```
String strDate = "20091504";
TemporalAccessor ta = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd").parse(strDate);
```

You will directly have an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
Text '20091504' could not be parsed:
Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 15
```

Comment: Seems this is not working correctly in the below case.

If I use the format 'dd-MM-yy' and parse the date value '31-02-19', it is not throwing any parse error instead it is providing the result '28-02-99' but I'm expecting to be throw parse exception since the given date is not a valid one. Did you encounter this case?

Comment: Using Java 11 and JShell, I obtain : `jshell> DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yy").parse("31-02-19"); $1 ==> {},ISO resolved to 2019-02-28` but this a different kind of invalid date as asked by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

By using Java 8 `LocalDate` you can write like this,

```
String strDate = "20091504";
LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse(strDate, DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);
System.out.println(date1);
```

Here is the Exception is thrown during parsing

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20091504' could not be parsed: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 15
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(Unknown Source)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.time.LocalDate.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.katte.infa.DateFormatDemo.main(DateFormatDemo.java:22)

Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 15
at java.time.temporal.ValueRange.checkValidIntValue(Unknown Source)
at java.time.temporal.ChronoField.checkValidIntValue(Unknown Source)
at java.time.chrono.IsoChronology.resolveYMD(Unknown Source)
at java.time.chrono.IsoChronology.resolveYMD(Unknown Source)
at java.time.chrono.AbstractChronology.resolveDate(Unknown Source)
at java.time.chrono.IsoChronology.resolveDate(Unknown Source)
at java.time.chrono.IsoChronology.resolveDate(Unknown Source)
at java.time.format.Parsed.resolveDateFields(Unknown Source)
at java.time.format.Parsed.resolveFields(Unknown Source)
at java.time.format.Parsed.resolve(Unknown Source)
at java.time.format.DateTimeParseContext.toResolved(Unknown Source)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(Unknown Source)
... 3 more
```

Comment: Really nitpicking, `BASIC_ISO_DATE` accepts an optional (and for most purposes meaningless) UTC offset as in `20090304+08` or `20221219-072345`, which the OP probably also didn’t want.

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

There are two answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53667215/10819573) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30830455/10819573)) already there using `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html). While I highly recommend using the first one, I have written this answer to clarify two important facts:

1. The [first one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53667215/10819573) uses a pre-defined formatter, `DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE`. It's important to note that all pre-defined formatters use [`ResolverStyle#STRICT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#STRICT) and therefore, this is the perfect pattern to validate your date string.
2. The [second one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30830455/10819573) uses a custom `DateTimeFormatter`, and by default, all custom `DateTimeFormatter` use `ResolverStyle#SMART`. It means that this solution validates `20091504` correctly because the range of month is from 1 to 12, it fails to validate a string like `20090230` in the desired manner. Since a month day can range from 1 to 31, the parser will auto-correct it to `2009-02-28`.

##### How to validate a date string strictly with a custom formatter?

Use [`DateTimeFormatter#withResolverStyle.STRICT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withResolverStyle-java.time.format.ResolverStyle-) as shown below:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDate = "20090230";

        DateTimeFormatter parserDefaultResStyl = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
        DateTimeFormatter parserStrictResStyl = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd")
                .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);

        System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(strDate, parserDefaultResStyl));

        try {
            System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(strDate, parserStrictResStyl));
        } catch (DateTimeException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            // throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2009-02-28
Text '20090230' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {YearOfEra=2009, DayOfMonth=30, MonthOfYear=2},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.