# I need to check a Regular expression

Tags: regex

I have a excel file that must have this name format, where `xxx` is a number and yymmdd is a date. Only `xxx` and `yymmdd` change, the rest is always the same.

```
CDFSDDRCxxxCurryymmdd.xls
```

What is a regex I can use to check if it is correct??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647893/regular-expression-leap-years-and-more is a good start, but I don't recommend using regex to validate dates.

Comment: @RogerLindsjö I'm open to sugestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# I think you can try something like this :

```
"CDFSDDRC(?<xxx>[0-9]+)Curr(?<yymmdd>[0-9][0-9][0|1][0-9][0-3][0-9])\.xls"
```

But you will have to check matches.Groups["yymmdd"].value once more to check for special cases such as `CDFSDDRC123Curr321539.xls` that match but contains an incorrect date.

Answer (score 3):

Try with following regex:

```
^CDFSDDRC\d{3}Curr\d{6}\.xls$
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work.

```
CDFSDDRC\d[3]Curr(([0-9]{2}(0[13578]|1[02])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))|([0-9]{2}(0[469]|1[1])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30))|([0-9]{2}(02)(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]))|((((04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))|00)(02)29))\.xsl
```

I think that you have to escape the backslashes in the C# string.

```
"CDFSDDRC\\d[3]Curr(([0-9]{2}(0[13578]|1[02])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))|([0-9]{2}(0[469]|1[1])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30))|([0-9]{2}(02)(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]))|((((04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))|00)(02)29))\\.xsl"
```