# Regex and Date pattern matching

Tags: java, regex

Below is the regex I am have:

```
Pattern ddpat = Pattern.compile( "(\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4})" );
```

For an invalid date pattern `02/29/1975` (Since it is not a leap year), when I try the above `REGEX` on this invalid date, I don't want my REGEX to match this invalid date.

Please suggest is there some way to achieve this.

Comment: that is not possible with Regex, you have to code these type validations

Comment: There is simply no answer to this question

Comment: Theoretically (!!!) you can create a regular expression enumerating (!!!) all valid dates, with factoring to reduce repetitions, (stopping today or at some point in the future). This will be a big regex, but it would be a "way to achieve this". (THIS IS NOT MEANT SERIOUSLY.)

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool for this job (checking validity of dates). The issue is not only with leap year, this regex will accept: `99/99/9999` as well ;)

Comment: I agree with this. But since this is an existing code working for years in production, I won't be able to change it any way, hence just trying to do something and let it work as of now.

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647893/regular-expression-leap-years-and-more/24390306#24390306); the regex there has a range from 1000 to 2999, validates leap years and optionally the time part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use `DateFormatter` in order to validate dates.

Not only that, you will have to set the DateFormat's [setLenient](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) to false in order to catch those kinds of errors

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String d = "02/29/1975";
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    sdf.setLenient(false);
    Date date = sdf.parse(d);
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

You will see that it throws the `ParseException`

If you don't set up the leniency, then the DateFormat will attempt to parse it to a convenient albeit arbitrary Date for example:

`02/29/1975` could be converted to `03/01/1975`

Comment: I am having an array of Date format something like this:DateFormat[] format = new DateFormat[]{
      new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"),
      new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy") }; In this case, how to use the setLenient ?

Comment: @WhoAmI loop over your format array and setLenient(false); before you use it

Comment: Rather than looping, is there any shortcut so that I can set it while declaring the array? I just want to optimize the code. Please suggest.

Comment: I believe by default DateFormat has leniency set to true... So I don't know if there's a way to overload it on construction.

Comment: @WhoAmI seriously, is  a three line code (if you separate the braces)
`for(DateFormat f : format) { f.setLenient(false);}`

Comment: Ok fine...have to take it. Now it the parsing fails, I am getting an exception: `ava.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "02/29/1975"`. I dont want to throw an exception but rather return the date itself. Can you please suggest how to avoid throwing exception?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58377/discussion-between-gtgaxiola-and-whoami).