# What do I need to change in my date RegEx to account for leap years?

Tags: javascript

I have separate input fields for month, day, and year. The current date regex does not account for leap years. I tried adding other regex to account for leap years but had no success. Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
var bmonth = Apperyio('register_birthdaymonth').val(); 
var bday = Apperyio('register_birthdayday').val(); 
var byear = Apperyio('register_birthdayyear').val(); 
var dateString = (bmonth + "/" + bday + "/" + byear)

var date_regex = /^(?:(0[1-9]|1[012])[\/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/.](18|19|20)[0-9]{2})$/;
if (!(date_regex.test(dateString)))
{   
    errorMsg = errorMsg + "1";
    document.getElementById("bdayError").innerHTML = "Please enter your birthday.";
}
```

Comment: Which date input fails for you ?

Comment: Leap years do not validate correctly. Example: It allows 02/29/1991.

Comment: Do you need a regex? You could use the date object. Like so: http://jsbin.com/kamebibena/3/edit?js,console,output In this way you could account for dates in the past fairly easily as well.

Comment: @John Thank you very much! This did the trick. It is working perfectly. I appreciate you taking the time to help.

Comment: @timmyusa no problem!

Answer (score 0):

Did you already look at this? [Regular Expression | Leap Years and More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647893/regular-expression-leap-years-and-more)

If not, try the following: 
`(02)[\/.]29[\/.](((18|19|20)(04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))|2000)`

Comment: When I replaced my current regex with the one you provided I received multiple errors including unexpected '/' 

How would I go about resolving this?