# How to use logic operator in Regex x <= y in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, numbers, logic

Hello i have regex like this

`^[\d]{4,5}([;]\d{4,5})*$|(^[\d]{4,4}([:]\d{4,5})$)|^[\d]{4,5}(\s[;]\s\d{4,5})*$|(^[\d]{4,4}(\s[:]\s\d{4,5})$)`

***I need effect like this:***

- 12345 : 12345 - allowed
- 12345 : 1234 - not allowed
- 12345 : 12344 - not allowed
- 1234 : 1235 - allowed
- 1234 : 12345 - allowed

***Generally - left <= right***

Rest can be stay

Someone know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Though people do [weird things](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8647893/1169519) with RegExps, it's better to do maths where math is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe cannot be described by a *regular language*, as such I doubt this can be solved with a regex. You could however solve this easily in JS:

```
 const [a, b] = str.split(":");
 if(+a <= +b) /*...*/
```

Comment: but i need rest of separator like " ; "

Comment: Then combine the two. Match with a regex, then iterate and validate.