# Java: Use an input/argument as a variable when variable could be in one of multiple inputs/arguments

Tags: java, variables, input, args

I have a java program that's extracting a date from the contents of a file, and then renaming the file with that date string. What I need to account for is that the new file name may end up having the date at the beginning, in the middle, or at the end. What I was trying to do was something like this -

```
String outputFilePt1 = args[0];
String outputFilePt2 = args[1];
String outputFilePt3 = args[2];

String outputDate = dateFormat.format( date );
String newOutputFile = outputFilePt1 + outputFilePt2 + outputFilePt3;
```

I would then enter something like "MyFile_", "outputDate", ".csv" for args 0-2, respectively, hoping that the result would be MyFile_outputDatesValue.csv - because I may need it to be MyFile.csv_outputDatesValue

What would be the best way to accomplish taking 3 inputs - FilePart1, FilePart2, FilePart3 where one would end up with the value of "outputDate" in the above code block?

Thanks in advance, I hope what I'm asking makes sense!

EDIT - I do not know the value of "outputDate" at the time I input the arguments. This is calculated based on the input file and a config/properties file that determines the date format/location of the input file.

Comment: hmmm... "MyFile" + ".csv" + "_outputDatesValue" ?

Comment: Show the signature if your method

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I don't know the value at the time of the input of the arguments. So I need to be able to enter a variable name, like "outputDate". Then if I put in arg0="MyFile_" arg1="outputDate" arg2=".csv" the result of my string is MyFile_xxxxx.csv - where "xxxxx" is actually the value calculated in my outputDate variable.

Comment: Can't you do what aluxa suggested above? Maybe change the format as you need - i.e. `String newOutputFile = outputFilePt1 + outputDate + outputFilePt3;` or similar. You don't need to pass an argument to a method if the value is set within a method itself.

Comment: Germann, thanks, the only problem is I don't know the value at the time I input the arguments. As such, I was hoping I could input outputDate as the value of one of the arguments, but if I do that it prints literally, i.e. "MyFile_outputDate.csv". If I can't do something like that, the next step would be to parse each input parms to look for the date, and format my final filename string accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [boolean String.matches(String regexp)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method. You can parse it like in this post: [Regex date format validation on Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149680/regex-date-format-validation-on-java) , find out which line arg is date and then I think it would be easy to build an appropriate string.

Comment: Thanks, vanomart. In this case I don't want to input a date format or an actual value. I am defining a dateformat using simpleDateFormat in my configuration file, so all I wanted to pass was "outputDate". Apparently, it just doesn't work this way. To do what I want, I'm basically just requiring that one of the arguments be "thedate" - and then I'm evaluating FilePt1, FilePt2, and FilePt3 against "thedate", and assigning outputDate to the argument that contains "thedate". That does what I need, just not exactly how I was hoping! Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the way I ended up going was just to accept a static string like "thedate" for the FilePart I want the date in, and then do a replace "thedate" in the file name string with the variable containing it, like this -

```
String outputFilePt1 = args[0];
String outputFilePt2 = args[1];
String outputFilePt3 = args[2];

String outputDate = dateFormat.format( date );
newOutputFile = newOutputFile.replaceAll("thedate", outputDate);
```

Thanks for all who looked and thought about this! The real answer to my question was "You can't do exactly what you want" - basically you have to convert the input, or replace it as per above. Before coming to this solution I had basically done -

```
String outputFilePt1 = args[0];
String outputFilePt2 = args[1];
String outputFilePt3 = args[2];
String lookingFor = "thedate";

if (outputFilePt1.equals(lookingFor))
{
    outputFilePt1 = outputDate;
}
if (outputFilePt2.equals(lookingfor))
{
    outputFilePt2 = outputDate;
}
if (outputFilePt2.equals(lookingfor))
{    
    outputFilePt3 = outputDate;
}

String outputDate = dateFormat.format( date );
```

Obviously, doing the replace on my "thedate" string was preferable!

Thanks again.