# Regex date validation for yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: java, android, regex, validation, date

what is the regex for the date format yyyy-mm-dd?

I want to validate the email from edittext and check if it matches the regex.

Comment: Also have a look to the right at the "Related" section, there are many similar cases of requests for RegEx strings for date validation.

Comment: Check this answer it may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/2149698/2675669

Answer (score 215):

This will match `yyyy-mm-dd` and also `yyyy-m-d`:

```
^\d{4}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

If you're looking for an exact match for `yyyy-mm-dd` then try this

```
^\d{4}\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```

or use this one if you need to find a date inside a string like `The date is 2017-11-30`

```
\d{4}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])*
```

https://regex101.com/r/acvpss/1

Comment: How did you produce the graph?

Comment: @AllanXu It is from the site called debuggex

Comment: Incomplete! The regular expression also matches 2016-02-31 while it shouldn't :(

Comment: @Djack What are you talking about? If you want to enforce actual dates on it, a regex is not the way to do it. Parse the date and make sure it's actually valid in whatever language you're using. This just ensures it's numbers, delimited with hyphens and is has a day that is feasible (less than 32)

Comment: @Vinod the regex allows 9 (with no preceding 0) to match as true. Was this intentional?

Comment: @AlanH You can use `/^\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/`. This way if leading zero is missing then the regexp will return false.

Comment: but it also accepts 2017-02-31

Comment: it also matches  2017-0210-31

Comment: This doesn't work perfectly, it accepts yyyy-m-d, it doesn't strictly enforce a yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: it matches "1984-9-3" portion of "1984-9-35".

Comment: With this regex you accept also `0000-01-01`, I used this one instead: `^([1-9][0-9]{3})\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$`

Comment: how would you do: yyyy/mm/dd

Comment: `\d{4}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])*` does not accept a date formatted `2023-02-30` in a string; in the original regex101 example you can just attache another `0` to the end of the example string to see it fail. `\d{4}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])*` works for a date formatted `yyyy-mm-dd` in a string.

Answer (score 79):

A simple one would be

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/d6O7Tw9uzQqyaRqK)

but this does not restrict month to 1-12 and days from 1 to 31.

There are more complex checks like in the other answers, by the way pretty clever ones. Nevertheless you have to check for a valid date, because there are no checks for if a month has 28, 30, or 31 days.

Comment: Wow. A first downvote after nearly 4 years. Isn't this worth another badge? ;)

Comment: Why plain wrong? The regex and stated limitations are correct. What do I miss?

Comment: It's not a real answer to the question because it does not validate dates, just validates "4 digits followed by a dash followed by 2 digits followed by a dash followed by 2 digits". Just like saying, 2+2 is 3 but you need to add 1. It's missleading.

Comment: It is also missleading to add this comment only to this answer. The other answers are also incorrect in this sense because they are also incomplete to validate it. But if you prefer I would call it a remark or large comment.

Comment: It's the fact that it has too many votes, nothing more in particular.

Comment: Upvoting to compensate for the downvote because it's the only answer that actually acknowledges its limitations. The higher voted answers don't invalidate Feb 31, for example. Capture the text fields with regex and validate with other sanity checks.

Answer (score 14):

You can use this regex to get the **yyyy-MM-dd** format:

```
((?:19|20)\\d\\d)-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-([12][0-9]|3[01]|0?[1-9])
```

You can find example for date validation: [How to validate date with regular expression.](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-date-with-regular-expression/)

Comment: He wanted yyyy-mm-dd.

Answer (score 8):

you can test this expression:

```
^\d{4}[\-\/\s]?((((0[13578])|(1[02]))[\-\/\s]?(([0-2][0-9])|(3[01])))|(((0[469])|(11))[\-\/\s]?(([0-2][0-9])|(30)))|(02[\-\/\s]?[0-2][0-9]))$
```

Description:
validates a yyyy-mm-dd, yyyy mm dd, or yyyy/mm/dd date

makes sure day is within valid range for the month - does NOT validate Feb. 29 on a leap year, only that Feb. Can have 29 days

Matches (tested) : 0001-12-31 | 9999 09 30 | 2002/03/03

Comment: Why was this answer down voted? It worked perfectly for me

Comment: Could you edit the answer and put the code in code-tags.

Comment: Editted into tag :)

Comment: This accepts both 2000-02-29 and 2001-02-29 as a match

Comment: But date could be 00