# how match and range string to regex in SWIFT

Tags: swift, regex

I need to validate date in string to the format of `yyyy-MM-dd` using regular expressions.

now I can check whether the string matches that format or not by:

```
if value.matches("^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}") {
```

but it also accepts `2009-90-90` and that's invalid date.

So how can I add range in my regular e.g no more than `12`months in the date.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex date validation for yyyy-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061723/regex-date-validation-for-yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to validate date format dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: Using a regex for this is a very bad choice of tools.

Answer (score 1):

A regex isn't the most appropriate way of validating a date. Use a date formatter instead:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()

formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let str = "2019-02-28"

let dateIsValid = formatter.date(from: str) != nil
```

Comment: But, what if my incoming data isn't standard? My dates are all dd-MMM-yyyy, but my dates times have different delimiters, sometimes a ":" and sometimes an "h".