# Cypress Testing - Expect a date format

Tags: testing, cypress, date-formatting

I'm creating a Cypress test to my rest call API. Anyways I need to verify a date format, for example, in my JSON Response I have:

"documentDate": "2022-01-28"

So, with that i need to verify the date format not its value. There is a way on Cypress "expect" to verify that? Idk, maybe something like:

```js
expect(documentDate)to.have.format('yyyy-MM-dd');
```

If anyone can help me, it will be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to use the [dayjs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/string-format) library.

The problem with regex is it only checks characters, not date validity

```js
import dayjs from 'dayjs'

it('checks date string is a valid date', () => {

  const documentDate = "2022-02-29"    // not valid but passes with regex

  const parsed = dayjs(documentDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')

  // fails with error "expected 2022-03-01 to equal 2022-02-29"
  expect(parsed.format('YYYY-MM-DD')).to.eq(documentDate)  
})
```

Comment: Thanks you dude, i'll probably use this as is more accurate to verify the date. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex for this. You can use the below regex, which has been taken from this [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061723/regex-date-validation-for-yyyy-mm-dd).

```js
/^\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/
```

In your test you can use:

```js
expect(documentDate).to.match(/^\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should us regex to match the format of your date.

`\d` is regex for matching any digit character (0-9)

`{}` is quantifier for the preceding token

```js
expect(documentDate).to.match(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/)
```

Comment: Thanks you, my friend, sure that helped alot.