# ASP.NET Core WEB ASP input format validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on web API (Asp.net core) I have a get method that takes (start and end date as input parameter)

I would like to make sure the date is in "YYYY-MM-DD" formats. otherwise, error "Date should be in YYYY-MM-DD format"

I am using fluent validation but not sure how to validate it. or via data annotation

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] DataParameter input) {    
}

public class DataParameter {
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

You can use string and [RegularExpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute?view=net-6.0)

```
public class DataParameter
{
   [RegularExpression(@"^\d{4}\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$", ErrorMessage = "Date should be in YYYY-MM-DD format")]
   public string StartDate { get; set; }

   [RegularExpression(@"^\d{4}\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$", ErrorMessage = "Date should be in YYYY-MM-DD format")]
   public string EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

The regex is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061723/regex-date-validation-for-yyyy-mm-dd)

Or create your own attribute, something like this

```
public class DateFormatAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string _format;

    public DateFormatAttribute(string format)
        : base($"Date should be in {format} format.")
    {
        _format = format;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value is not string dateStr)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return DateTime.TryParseExact(dateStr, _format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out _);
    }
}
```

Then use it as follows

```
[DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")]
public string StartDate { get; set; }
```

FluentValidation implementation

```
RuleFor(c => c.StartDate)
   .Must(x => DateTime.TryParseExact(x, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out _))
   .When(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.StartDate))
   .WithMessage("Date should be in yyyy-MM-dd format");
```

> Note that StartDate and EndDate are strings

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. How can I handle it via flaunt validation?

Comment: What do you need, FluentValidation or Data Annotation? The question says about both. Please clarify. And you didn't show us your Validator

Comment: Hi Roman, sorry for my mistake, fluent validation because I want to do a unit test. Thanks

Comment: @itmannz see update

Comment: Why StartDate and EndDate are string?

why not Date and time?

Comment: because DateTime stores the date and time without any specific format