# How to check if values in an array of objects have a date format and how to reorder array by date if so?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, date

I have an array of data like so:

```
let arrayData =[
    {
        "category": "2019-07-24",
        "total": 1,
        "Col 1": 100
    },
    {
        "category": "2018-11-12",
        "total": 3,
        "Col 1": 101
    },
    {
        "category": "2019-07-11",
        "total": 1,
        "Col 1": 200
    },
    {
        "category": "2019-08-11",
        "total": 1,
        "Col 1": 153
    },
    {
        "category": "2019-09-25",
        "total": 1,
        "Col 1": 198
    }
]
```

How can I check if every 'category' value inside the array is in the format YYYY-MM-DD? And if so, re-order the objects inside the array by earliest date?

I know that I can use regex like so to check for individual dates:

```
checkIfDateIsInRightFormat() {
  // Is this the best way?
  const regex = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/;

  if (dateStr.match(regex) === null) {
    return false;
  }

  const date = new Date(dateStr);

  const timestamp = date.getTime();

  if (typeof timestamp !== 'number' || Number.isNaN(timestamp)) {
    return false;
  }

  return date.toISOString().startsWith(dateStr);
}
```

and then I can do this:

```
let arrayOfItems = []

this.arrayData.foreach(item => {
     arrayOfItems.push(this.checkIfDateIsInRightFormat(item))
})

let result = arrayOfItems.every(element => {
    if (element === array[0] && element === true) {
      return true;
    }
});


if(result  === true) {
    // Here I'll order the objects in arrayData by earliest date in 'category'
    arrayData.sort(
      (objA, objB) => Number(objB.category) - Number(objA.category),
    );
}
```

However, it doesn't work as intended. How would I be able to achieve the right result?

**Based on the arrayData above, the result should be:**

```
let newArrayData =[
    {
        "category": "2018-11-12",
        "total": 3,
        "Col 1": 101
    },
    {
        "category": "2019-07-11",
        "total": 1,
        "Col 1": 200
    },
    {
        "category": "2019-07-24",
        "total": 1,
        "Col 1": 100
    },
    {
        "category": "2019-08-11",
        "total": 1,
        "Col 1": 153
    },
    {
        "category": "2019-09-25",
        "total": 1,
        "Col 1": 198
    }
]
```

Otherwise if I have something like this:

```
let exampleArrayData =[
    {
        "category": "2018-11-12",
        "total": 3,
        "Col 1": 101
    },
    {
        "category": "ABC",
        "total": 1,
        "Col 1": 200
    },
]
```

It would stop at finding out that they are not all dates. result = false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way I think:

```js
let newArrayData = false;
let arrayData =[
    {
        "category": "2019-07-24",
        "total": 1,
        "Col 1": 100
    },
    {
        "category": "2018-11-12",
        "total": 3,
        "Col 1": 101
    },
    {
        "category": "2019-07-24",
        "total": 1,
        "Col 1": 200
    },
    {
        "category": "2019-08-11",
        "total": 1,
        "Col 1": 153
    },
    {
        "category": "2019-09-25",
        "total": 1,
        "Col 1": 198
    }
];

if (arrayData.every(x => new Date(x.category) !== "Invalid Date"  && !isNaN(new Date(x.category)))){
    newArrayData = arrayData.slice().sort((a, b) => new Date(a.category) - new Date(b.category));
}

console.log(newArrayData);
```

.every() checks whether all items fulfill a condition.

By trying to convert the strings into a date, we can check whether they result in "Invalid Date" (which is returned by the new Date object in case of an invalid date) and if it is a number (ms since January 1, 1970).
Now if you really want to make sure, that the strings are EXACTLY in YYYY-MM-DD format, then yes, you need regex, see: [Regex date validation for yyyy-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061723/regex-date-validation-for-yyyy-mm-dd)

.slice() is only there to first make a copy of the array and can be omitted if you don't care about manipulating the original array, which .sort() otherwise does by default.