# How we can get Image from Sdcard which have unique name based on timestamp in Android

Tags: android, timestamp, android-sdcard

I know how to retrieve image from sdcard but i can't find solution of retrieving specific image which contains unique timestamp with its name.

How can i get image from sdcard which has unique timestamp while i storing into External directory.?

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

//folder stuff
File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImages");
imagesFolder.mkdirs();

File image = new File(imagesFolder, "QR_" + timeStamp + ".png");
Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
```

How can i retrieve above image from sdcard?

Comment: I would use Java's regular expressions to find those specific images.

Comment: Please Can you explain with example ?

Comment: Read for example this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149680/regex-date-format-validation-on-java after i hope you will have a good understanding how to look for files with your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This below code is to retrieve the files from the folder with filename start with **"QR_[eight int '-' six int]"**

```
private void getFiles() {
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImages");

    String path = imagesFolder.getAbsolutePath();

    final String where = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ";
    final String[] args = new String[]{path + File.separator + "QR_" + "%"};
    final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    final Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, columns, where, args, null);
    final String pattern = Pattern.quote(path) + "/[^/]*";

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        do {
            final String curPath = cursor.getString(0);
            if (curPath.matches(pattern)) {
                final File file = new File(curPath);
                    if(file.getName().matches("\\d{8}-\\d{6}")) {
                        // your file
                    }
            }
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: But problem is cuurent timestamp is differ than img storing timestamp

Comment: So you want file name with "QR_" +[anything] + ".png"..?

Comment: not anything but i want to store image with unique name and later i want to retrieve that image

For unique name i use timestamp variable that contains value of``yyyyMMdd_HHmmss`