# Is there a way to format the input from a user, using the Scanner?

Tags: java

I am trying to build a program that asks a user for their DOB and will throw an error if not in the DD/MM/YYYY format. Does anyone know how to make that happen?
I apologize if I didn't do enough research but I couldn't really find anything about formatting the input for a date.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Check the date format of current string is according to required format or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20231539/java-check-the-date-format-of-current-string-is-according-to-required-format-or). Getting a String from the user is common enough that you can find info on how to do that as well.

Comment: Parse the string as a date and catch the parse exception.

Comment: "and will throw an error if not in the DD/MM/YYYY format" in that case simply accept user data as string, then check if it matches `dd/dd/dddd` where `d` is digit. You are use regex for that, or if you want to check if not only format is correct but also content you can try parsing this string into actual date.

Comment: *"I couldn't really find anything about formatting the input for a date"* That is because you don't *format* the input, you *parse* it. Try searching for that instead.

Comment: @takendarkk Yes getting a string is easy to do, what I am trying to get is a string formatted a specific way. It doesn't appear that anything in that link addresses that.

Comment: @Andreas I might have used the wrong language when asking the question. My apologies. I will look under parsing the string instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to process the input after it's read.  Regular expressions are very efficient in this task.  `^\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}$` will check that the user supplied string is in DD/MM/YYYY.

So, you could [compare the user input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2149692/4678883) as follows:

```
if(userStr.matches("^\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}$")){
    //Do stuff if input is good
}else{
    //Do stuff if input is bad
}
```

Comment: Where would you put this?

Answer (score -1):

```
boolean isDOB(String input) {
        String[] inputs = input.split("/");
        if(inputs.length!=3)
            return false;
        int days = Integer.parseInt(inputs[0]);
        int month = Integer.parseInt(inputs[1]);        
        if(days>31 || month>12 || inputs[2].length()!=4) {
            return false;           
        }
        return true;        
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the entire program if this helps you. This also validates the date using [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). So, if user enters `32/01/2000`, it fails.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DateOfBirth {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter your DOB");
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = myScanner.next();
        while (!validDate(input)) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid date. Please enter your DOB");
            input = myScanner.next();
        }
        myScanner.close();
    }

    private static boolean validDate(String input) {
        try {
            DateTimeFormatter inputFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
            LocalDate.parse(input, inputFormat);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Down voter - can you tell me why you have down voted this? Do you see any issue with this solution?