# Spring @ExceptionHandler overriding input exceptions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception

When calling GET endpoint in my scenario you must inform two input parameters `code` and `date`, the first one is annotated with `@Size(min = 2, max = 2)` the second with `@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)`. Said that, if you pass `code` = 123 and `date` = 2000-01-AA, you must receive two error messages one regarding `ConstraintViolationException` and `MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException` respectively.

Here is my code:

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler({MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class, ConstraintViolationException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public ErrorResponse handleArgumentTypeMismatch(RuntimeException ex) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = ErrorResponse.builder().status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value())
                .message(INVALID_VALUES_MESSAGE).errorDetail(new ErrorDetail(ex.getMessage())).build();
        return errorResponse;
    }
}
```

Currently, I'm only receiving the last parameter error message, in this case `date`, and the Spring is ignoring the `code`, is there any way to receive both error messages for `code` and `date`?

Comment: DateTimeFormat is not a validation annotation. It tells Spring how to turn the string it receives into a Date. And only if the string can successfully be parsed, then the bean containing this date can be created, and validated. There's no way to validate a bean if it can't even be created due to an incorrect date format.

Comment: Got it, so a possible solution should be, remove the annotation @DateTimeFormat, and add a regex to validate the date format as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2149692/4192045). This approach has a trade-off, where I will have to execute the parse afterward Spring validates the input parameters. So, in the end, I will not accomplish the idea of having both error messages together.