# Get a File With SFTP using Pentaho Kettle

Tags: javascript, etl, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I have files on SFTP with the name format as:

- 145388__transaction-search_Bede7d_20230823080418000000_101e736810b34134.csv
- 145388__transaction-search_Bede7d_20230822080346000000_41314bd7d21cda0e.csv

I want to get only those files from SFTP which has `Bede7d_TodaysDate`. So `Bede7d_20230823`.
I used this formula in the wildcard option under Files tab in "Get a file with SFTP" with regex as `.*Bede7d_\d{8}.*`

I tried entering regex -
`.*Bede7d_\d{8}.*`

And was expecting to get only
`145388__transaction-search_Bede7d_20230823080418000000_101e736810b34134.csv`

But I am getting all the files starting with `Bede7d_.`

It does not work. Any suggestion please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the filenames you are trying to read, the regular expression `.*Bede7d_\d{8}.*` will match both the files. Since `\d{8}` will match all 8 digits after `.*Bede7d_`. More info on regular expression in this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2149692/1131789

To answer your question, if you want to filter only the files that matches the current date, you can try the below options:

1. Change the Regular expression (wildcard) to: `.*Bede7d_20230823.*` where 20230823 is the current date. You can also set the date as a variable in PDI.

[image]

2. Another option, keep your previous regular expression as `.*Bede7d_\d{8}` and use a "Filter Step" in Pentaho DI to filter the necessary files based on the current date.

Comment: option 2 all the way for me