# Weird date parsing in Java

Tags: java, parsing, date

I am trying to do date validation. When the user enters something like: 2552533 Jan 2012 1340001 this gets parsed as: Wed Sep 03 07:41:00 EDT 9000. Here is my code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy kkmm");
...
Date test;
try {
    test = sdf.parse(dateString);
} catch (Exception e) {
...
```

Here `dateString` is a string that I'm trying to parse into a date. If the string isn't a valid date, like: 552533 Jan 2012 1340001, I was hoping for an error to be thrown.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Knee-jerk response: Have you tried Joda Time? http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Freiheit - JodaTime is _always_ worth posting if someone isn't using it. It isn't _just_ a Knee-jerk response if the difference it makes is like breathing and drowning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (before parsing the actual date):

```
sdf.setLenient(false);
```

#### See also:

- [Make SimpleDateFormat.parse() fail on invalid dates (e.g. month is greater than 12)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905551)

Comment: I'm very fond of one line solutions.  Thanks for the help, it works as expected now.

Answer (score 2):

`SimpleDateFormat.parse` does not throw any exception in case of error, it returns `null`. From the javadoc:

```
 Returns:
     A Date parsed from the string. In case of error, returns null.  
 Throws:
     NullPointerException - if text or pos is null.
```

So you can do:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy kkmm");
...
Date test = sdf.parse(dateString);
if(test == null) {
   // there was an error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Tudor mentions, `SimpleDateFormat` does not throw an exception when it fails to parse. One alternative is `DateUtils.parseDate90` ([javadocs](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html#parseDate%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)) from the Apache Commons available [here](http://commons.apache.org/lang).